# Get the id of firebase data

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I use a `ListView` to show the data stored in Firebase database and when I long click on a list item I want to get the auto-generated Id of the list item source in Firebase to be able to update or delete data by getting the Id.

```
patientListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Patient p = patientList.get(position);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE**: I use this to add data to my database

```
try {
                    String name = mNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                    String phone = mPhoneEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                    String age = mAgeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                    String aptDate = date();
                    String visitType = radioListener();

                    String gender = mGenderSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String descCondition = mDescCondEditText.getText().toString().trim();


                    if (name.isEmpty()) {
                        mNameEditText.setError("Enter Your Name Please!");
                        mNameEditText.requestFocus();
                    } else if (phone.isEmpty()) {
                        mPhoneEditText.setError("Enter Your Phone");
                        mPhoneEditText.requestFocus();
                    } else if (age.isEmpty()) {
                        mAgeEditText.setError("Enter Your Age");
                        mAgeEditText.requestFocus();
                    } else if (aptDate.isEmpty()) {
                        dateEditText.setError("Please Enter Appointment Date");
                        dateEditText.requestFocus();
                    } else {

                        Patient appointment = new Patient(name, phone, age, descCondition, gender, aptDate, visitType);
                        mDatabaseRef.push().setValue(appointment);
                        successAlertDialog();
                        mNameEditText.setText("");
                        mPhoneEditText.setText("");
                        mAgeEditText.setText("");
                        dateEditText.setText("");
                        mGenderSpinner.setSelection(0);
                        mDescCondEditText.setText("");
                    }
```

and this is my module class 
package com.sharhospital;

```
public class Patient {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String age;
    private String describeCond;
    private String gender;
    private String date;
    private String typeOfVisit;
    private String docName;

    public Patient(String name, String phone, String age, String describeCond, String gender, String date, String typeOfVisit) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.age = age;
        this.describeCond = describeCond;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.date = date;
        this.typeOfVisit = typeOfVisit;
    }

    public Patient(String name, String phone, String age, String describeCond, String gender, String date, String typeOfVisit, String docName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.age = age;
        this.describeCond = describeCond;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.date = date;
        this.typeOfVisit = typeOfVisit;
        this.docName = docName;
    }

    public Patient() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getDescribeCond() {
        return describeCond;
    }

    public void setDescribeCond(String describeCond) {
        this.describeCond = describeCond;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTypeOfVisit() {
        return typeOfVisit;
    }

    public void setTypeOfVisit(String typeOfVisit) {
        this.typeOfVisit = typeOfVisit;
    }

    public String getDocName() {
        return docName;
    }

    public void setDocName(String docName) {
        this.docName = docName;
    }
}
```

onItemLongListerner after changes

```
patientListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Patient p = patientList.get(position);
                 String Id = p.getId();
             mDatabaseRef.child(Id).removeValue();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

sending data to database

```
 String id = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
 Patient appointment = new Patient(id,name, phone, age, descCondition, gender, aptDate, visitType);
  mDatabaseRef.child(id).setValue(appointment);
```

[image]

Comment: See my answer here, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924912/

Comment: Why not store the auto-generated id as a property of your `Patient` class?

Comment: @AlexMamo that's may be it, but still I don't know how achieve that either

Comment: When you add the patient to the database, store that pushed id into a variable.

Comment: @AlexMamo if you have a code sample, it will help a lot

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you are using to add a `Patient` object to the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change your class to:

```
public class Patient {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String age;
    private String describeCond;
    private String gender;
    private String date;
    private String typeOfVisit;
    private String docName;

    public Patient(String id, String name, String phone, String age, String describeCond, String gender, String date, String typeOfVisit) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.age = age;
        this.describeCond = describeCond;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.date = date;
        this.typeOfVisit = typeOfVisit;
    }

    public Patient(String id, String name, String phone, String age, String describeCond, String gender, String date, String typeOfVisit, String docName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.age = age;
        this.describeCond = describeCond;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.date = date;
        this.typeOfVisit = typeOfVisit;
        this.docName = docName;
    }

    public Patient() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getDescribeCond() {
        return describeCond;
    }

    public void setDescribeCond(String describeCond) {
        this.describeCond = describeCond;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTypeOfVisit() {
        return typeOfVisit;
    }

    public void setTypeOfVisit(String typeOfVisit) {
        this.typeOfVisit = typeOfVisit;
    }

    public String getDocName() {
        return docName;
    }

    public void setDocName(String docName) {
        this.docName = docName;
    }
}
```

When you add the data to the database, use the following lines of code:

```
String id = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
Patient appointment = new Patient(id, name, phone, age, descCondition, gender, aptDate, visitType);
mDatabaseRef.child(id).setValue(appointment);
```

Now, in the `onItemLongClick()` method:

```
patientListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Patient p = patientList.get(position);
            String id = p.getId();
            mDatabaseRef.child(id).removeValue(); //Remove that particular object
            return false;
        }
    });
```

P.S. This will work only for the newly added objects because only those objects contain the id.

Comment: I get null for String Id, with newly added objects too

Comment: Have you removed all the data in the database and added a fresh one? Once all the objects will contain the id, there will be no NullPointerException. Do that and tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes, I removed all the data and added new ones

Comment: Show me your new database schema and the changed code.

Comment: Please add it to your question, so I can see it well formated. Show me also your new database schema, as requested before.

Comment: updated again, it giver a warning that id might be null when I send the data to firebase

Comment: I will ask you again, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I added the picture, It looks like it assigns the id to name field

Comment: The problem is that you have added the pushed id, into the `name` variable and **not** in the `id` variable that was added in the class. Please use the content of the `Patient` that exists in my answer and not yours, as it does **not** contain that id. Try that and tell me if it works.